# C++ modff error

Tags: c++, math

I should to cut the value to int and float parts. Like '21' - want to get '2' and '1' as ints.

```
float fp; // float part
float fp1; // new "int-style" float part
float ip; // int part

fp = modff(21.0/10, &ip);
ip = ip*10; // there i will get the '2'. Its works fine
fp1 = fp*10; // there i will get a null (0.09999999 by debugger, 
but should to be 0.99+)...
```

But with any other value, '22' for instance, 
    it is will work. 
    fine also. Whats wrong? :(

Seems like this function doesn't like the unit

==================================

Yeah easy fixed! :) I used 'modf' instead of 'modff'. It has 'double' datatype, so it works fine now )

Thanks for the answers

Comment: `21` doesn't have a fractional part. It will give `21` integral part and `0` fractional part. I don't understand your question.

Comment: interjay> I wan't to get the '21' as '2' and '1'. I have converted '21' to '2.1' before rest operations.
Ah sorry, my fault. Forgot to note the '21.0/10'

Comment: Please post some code **that you have tested**, and say what it outputs and what you expected. You obviously haven't tested the code posted here because you keep editing it to fix errors.

Comment: I'll notice it, sorry

Comment: So you want to break a `float` apart into its place values and save each as an `int`? Such as converting `374` to `3`, `7`, and `4`? It looks like one of the problems you may be having is [floating point inaccuracies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples).

Comment: Yeah. As i already said, my way works with any x2 values (22,23,24+ etc), but doesn't work with '21' with strange reason...

Comment: Search (on this site or Google) for "floating point arithmetic," "floating point inaccuracy," etc. The problem is with the way floats represent the decimal value of `2.1` and many other numbers. It's kind of a thick subject, but it's necessary to understand at least the basics of why it works as it does. Someone else who understands it better may be able to give you a good quick explanation for your particular problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answ^^. Im gone to searching about it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In floating point, when you do 21.0 / 10.0 you generally dont get 2.1. What you get is 2.099 or something like that due to floating point inaccurancy.

```
float fp; // float part
float fp1; // new "int-style" float part
float ip; // int part

float value = 21.0;
float part = 10.0;
fp = modf(value / part, &ip);
fp1 = value - (ip * part); //gives you 21 - (2 * 10) = 1

//ip = 2
//fp1 = 1
```

Comment: thanks ) 
'modf' instead 'modff' rulez ^^

Comment: And when you do 1/3 you don't get one-third because of integer inaccuracy. Same problem, but programmers learn to accept it with integer types.